# Can I make a UK visa application with my OLD passport number and wait for my new passport?

Tags: visas, uk

My old passport was damaged by a cup of coffee, so I have to renew it. It will take around 2 weeks for the new passport to come. But I'm in a hurry to apply for a Tier 4 UK visa.

The old passport was snipped by the authority and would no longer be valid. But all my personal information including the number can be recognized. And the number will be noted on my new passport.

Can I make an application or even an appointment with my old passport number, and get to the visa center with my new passport?

It would be very nice of you if you can answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be OK as long as you submit both *old* and new passports together at the VFS.

If you no longer have the old one or it is damaged to a point where you cannot be recognised as the holder you will need to change the application. They will allow for *innocuous* pen and ink corrections, but not for the passport number. 
 And you cannot show up at the VFS at collection time with a different passport.

As you have already 'locked down' your application, you may need to submit a fresh application.

---

Notes:

*Paragraphs 24* and *V 2.2 (d)* require a valid travel document. "Valid" in this context is undefined and intentionally ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you very much. My old passport was snipped by the authority, though my personal information can still be recognized. And the old number will be noted in my new passport. So I guess I can just make my application now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, a visa can be issued in an old passport as soon:

it is still valid by the time of the visa application
meet the criteria about free pages availables(varies from country to country)
meet the criteria about expiration date of the passport + visa (varies from country to country)

example: it is quite normal to get a 10 years USA visa in Colombian Passport, but some passports are valid only 5 years... so you normally will need both, the old-expired(with a valid visa) and the new one...